# Redux Toolkit array definition

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to learn redux-toolkid. I'm trying to pull data by defining data in array in Redux-Toolkid. But when I define as below, I get the error in the picture.
Describing
const newList = {
id: "1",
text: "cc",
};
Unfortunately, despite all my attempts, I could not define it as an array.

```
`import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {Provider, useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {configureStore, createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action) => {
      const newList = {
        id: "1",
        text: "cc",
    };
      state.push( newList);
    },
    deincrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export const {increment, deincrement, incrementByAmount} = counterSlice.actions;

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <First />
        <Second />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const First = () => {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 40}}>First : {counter}</Text>

      <Button title={'-'} onPress={() => dispatch(deincrement())} />
    </View>
  );
};

const Second = () => {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  console.log(counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Second : {counter}</Text>
      <Button title={'+'} onPress={() => dispatch(increment())} />
    </View>
  );
};

const newList = {
        id: "1",
        text: "cc",
    };`
```

You can find the photo here

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *have* defined it as an `array`, and that's the problem!

The value of `counter` here is an `array`:

```
const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
```

So you will get an error on these lines:

```
<Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 40}}>First : {counter}</Text>
```

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Second : {counter}</Text>
```

You cannot use `{counter}` inline with your text because it's not a text, it's an `array` of `object`s.

It's actually okay to have an `array` as a child if it's an array of `string`, `number`, etc.  But when React tries to render the first element of your `array` it finds an `object` (`{ id: "1",  text: "cc" }`) and it cannot render this.

If you are just playing around and want to see the value of the `state` then try this:

```
<Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 40}}>First : {JSON.stringify(counter)}</Text>
```

Be aware that only your `increment` action will work.  Dispatching `deincrement` or `incrementByAmount` will cause fatal errors in the reducer because your `state` is an `array` and `state.value` is not defined.